# Add Custom url tracking code before routing using urls.py in django

Tags: python, django

I want to build a server side base for analytics using Python/Django. The script should catch requested urls and update the database before routing the url requested using urls.py. How can this be done??

Comment: Do you need real time data? If not, then you can process your server logs at certain intervals to get all the requested urls. It will save a lot of unnecessary database writes while website rendering.

Answer (score 1):

To do such things you should use [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/). Copying from the documentation:

> Middleware is a framework of hooks into Django’s request/response processing. It’s a light, low-level “plugin” system for globally altering Django’s input or output.

A middleware is a simple class that can define a number of methods. You'd need to define the `process_request` or `process_view` method and there do your database updates etc

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/):

```
class MyTrackingMiddleware(object):  
    def process_request(self, request):  
        # save your request path here
        return None
```

And add it MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py